# AddDataField function fails with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: excel-interop

I am trying to recreate VBA code in C# to generate a pivot table

The VBA code is

```
                Sheets.Add
                ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:= xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                    "Sheet1!R1C1:R6C4", Version:= 6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
                    "Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:= "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= 6
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Cells(3, 1).Select
                With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("First Name")
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = 1
                End With
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(_
                    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Salary"), "Sum of Salary", xlSum
```

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

...
               //Start of pivot code
                workbook.Worksheets.Add();
                //ideally would want a "used range" here not specific cell addresses Sheet1!R1C1:R6C4
                pivotcache = (Excel.PivotCache)excel.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches().Create(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, "Sheet1!R1C1:R6C4", 6); // Const xlDatabase = 1 Member of Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType
                pivot = pivotcache.CreatePivotTable("Sheet2!R3C1", "PivotTable1", 6);
                sheet = (Excel.Worksheet) workbook.Worksheets["Sheet2"];
                range = sheet.get_Range("A3");
                range.Select();

                pf = pivot.PivotFields("First Name");
                pf.Orientation=XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField; //1=xlrowfield
                pf.Position = 1;

                //*****Code fails here ***
                df = pivot.AddDataField(pivot.PivotFields("Salary"), "Sum of Salary", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum); //Const xlSum = -4157 (&HFFFFEFC3) Member of Excel.XlConsolidationFunction
```

The last line fails with console error message: Error: Operation is not supported on this platform. Line: System.Private.CoreLib

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Disaggregating the code and adding orientation xlDataField like this worked

```
df = pivot.PivotFields("Salary");
df.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
df.Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum; 
df.Caption = "Sum of Salary";
```